# Azerothcore modules errors

Tags: module, azerothcore

I am new to this. I was able to put together my azerothcore server. I was trying to add modules, and I keep getting these errors in cmake:

```
CMake Error: File D:/AzerothCore/azerothcore-wotlk/modules/ModulesLoader.cpp.in.cmake does not exist.
CMake Error at modules/CMakeLists.txt:168 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:266 (ConfigureScriptLoader)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -3):

The solution to your problem involves a few simple steps to ensure the modules are correctly integrated. Here's how you can attempt to resolve the issues you're facing:

Firstly, I would visit this link and thoroughly follow the steps described: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/installing-a-module

**Re-Run CMake:** Whenever you add new modules to your server, it's essential to re-run CMake. This process helps in integrating the new modules with the existing build configuration.

**Maintain Original Module Folder Names:** The name of the module's folder is crucial for successful integration. For instance, if you're adding the **Eluna** module, ensure that the folder name remains `mod-eluna`. Changing the folder name can lead to issues in recognizing the module correctly.

**Correctly Clone the Module:** To add a module, you should clone it directly into the modules folder of your AzerothCore repository without specifying a new folder name. Use the git clone command followed by the module's GitHub repository URL. Here's an example command for adding the Eluna module:

```
cd path/to/azerothcore-wotlk/modules/
git clone https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-eluna.git
```

This ensures that the module is cloned with the correctf older structure, which is crucial for successful integration.

**Clean and Rebuild After Re-Running CMake:** After successfully adding the module and re-running CMake, it's a good practice to open your project solution and perform a clean/rebuild. This ensures that any pre-existing configurations that might conflict with the newly added modules are cleared.

**Optional Cleanup Tip:** If you're encountering persistent issues, consider deleting your project's build and install folders before re-running CMake. This approach provides a clean slate for the build configuration and can help avoid pitfalls. Ensure you backup any core edits you've made (if any) to avoid losing your work.

By following these steps, you should be able to add new modules to your solution without encountering those CMake errors.

Remember, the key lies in maintaining the correct folder structure and ensuring that CMake is re-run whenever modules are added or updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: I'll take that as a compliment @DavidW